# Javafx sound play stopped after seconds

Tags: javafx

i want to play a sound when i start run the program...... the sound playing is working but he is stopped after seconds(about 7 seconds) what is the prob?
Here is the code that i used it to play sound

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
   MediaPlayer m=new MediaPlayer(new Media(new File("n.mp3").toURI().toString()));
   Pane root=new Pane();
   //MediaView mv=new MediaView(m);

  m.play();
   //root.getChildren().add(mv);

     primaryStage.setTitle("Audio Player 1");
    primaryStage.setWidth(200);
    primaryStage.setHeight(200);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using AudioClip class since MediaPlayer is meant for conbinnig with MediaView with use case such as controlls

AudioClip au = new AudioClip(MyClassName.class.getResource("n.mp3").toString());
        au.play();

Comment: Thanks a lot dude you saved me on this one you have no idea.